# Visual studio code is stuck on Select Python Interpreter

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2

I am trying to run a jupyter notebook on my Windows machine by using WSL2 to run it in Ubuntu 20.04. It was working perfectly fine yesterday but today it's not selecting a Python Interpreter. I have tried reinstalling Ubuntu, Anaconda and Visual Studio Code.

When I run

```sh
code path_to_notebook.ipynb
```

It opens the window below:

[visual_studio_code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ClXc0.png)

After a couple seconds the box (that I've made a yellow square around) pops up. When I click in the "Select Python Interpreter" button and select the interpreter that I want (`~/anaconda3/bin/python`) nothing happens.

The Select Python Interpreter (red box) also stays there.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten around the problem by using `$ jupyter notebook --no-browser` in the terminal.

Unfortunately, this means that additional computer resources are required to run the notebook in my browser over a text editor. But it gets the job done.